# TYPO3 9.5.5 - Speaking URLs not generated in a second menu

Tags: slug, typo3-9.x

In my current TYPO3 9.5.5 "classic mode" project, 3 menu blocks are managed in folder sturctures like this:

```
RootPage
- Home (-> this is a separate menu)
- [FOLDER FOR MAIN MENU]
-- Menu 1
-- Menu 2
-- Menu 3
- [FOLDER FOR META MENU]
-- Contact
-- Privacy Protection
```

The menu is generated via MenuProcessors like this:

```
page.10.FLUIDTEMPLATE.dataProcessing {
        // Main menu
        20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        20 {
            special = directory
            special.value = {$mainMenuFolderPid}
            as = menuMain
            titleField = nav_title // title
            expandAll = 1
            includeSpacer = 0
            levels = 3
        }

        // Meta menu
        25 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        25 {
            special = directory
            special.value = {$metaMenuFolderPid}
            as = menuMeta
                       ...
        }
}
```

While the `home menu` and the `main menu` work as expected in respect to speaking urls, the `meta menu` does not create speaking urls correctly, but instead uses the page title directly, meaning that the "c" in `Contact` is indeed capitalized, so are the "p"s in `Privacy Protection`, which also has and empty space. 
The resulting URL format looks like this:

```
https://domain.tld/Contact
https://domain.tld/Privacy Protection
```

which causes a 404 (the one defined in “site configuration”; 404 works fine).

If I change the meta menu to `list` and add the page ids manually, the same wrong result for that menu is generated.

Strangely enough, when opening the contact page directly from the backend, the correct url (domain.tld/contact.html) is generated (even if I rename the slug manually).

Can anybody help me understand, what I am doing wrong here, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sound like a misspelled object notation in the menu provider. A link will be generated, if you use `menuItem.link`. But it seems you get the title with something like `menuItem.page.title`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out, there is a third player in the game by the name of Fluid. And there a stupid typo was hidden within all those fancy tags... Instead of addressing the `item.link` in the href tag, I instead used `item.page.title`, which generated the undesired output. My bad...